# How to reinforce a curtain rod

Tags: repair, curtain-rail

I have a ceiling that literally cannot be drilled into. An experienced handyman couldn't do it with high quality masonry bits.

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to reinforce a curtain rod, so that it will span a longer distance without slouching.

[image: curtain rod]

There isn't much room on either side.

[image: edge]

Comment: Was your handyman using a hammer drill or just an ordinary one? If you really can't add an anchor in the middle, going to a bigger rod will be your best bet.

Comment: You literally need a better handyman.

Comment: There are a lot of surfaces I won't drill.  I glue.  Good prep, West System epoxy, lots of gluing filler, a piece of hardwood, find a way to clamp/jack/brace it... Once it cures, screw into the hardwood. It would take trained termites to get it off though.

Answer (score 1):

Best thought I've got is to put a valance across the top of that opening, and put a middle support from the valance to the rod. Or switch to a 1" rod.

Answer (score 0):

A larger, round rod might let you put a dowel in the middle of it - but simply using a larger, round rod might itself be adequate, and simpler. Those C shaped "rods" are terribly weak.

Answer (score 0):

Use different materials. McMaster-Carr has a catalog full of them.  Anything from aluminum to carbon fiber.

Even easier, you might try 3/4" or 1" EMT thinwall electrical conduit tubing.  (Actual dimensions 1-1/16 and 1-5/16 respectively).  They build [geodesic domes](http://www.desertdomes.com/tips.html) with the stuff, their technique is to crush each end in a vise or press, and fasten to the flattened ends.  About $7 for a 10 foot stick.

I find heavier pipe isn't necessarily stiffer.  EMT is designed to span some distance, pipe is not.